# Getting stack trace for an error when running code from the console in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, stack-trace

I am calling a function from the console but when it throws an exception I do not receive a stack trace like I would if the code was executed normally.

Is there a way I can modify my command (perhaps with try/catch) to have it provide me this information?

**to clarify:**

page.js:

```
function otherStuff() { return ['a','b',undefined,'c'];
function doStuff() {
    var x = otherStuff();
    var z = parseInt(x[2]); // this will throw an error
}
```

console, after loading a html page that links page.js

```
> otherStuff();
```

I get no line number from the Error that is returned to me. When running it from the page (instead of the console) i would receive a line number and a stack trace.

Comment: what is the command? what version of chrome? (what is your mother's maiden name?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although verbose, this will print the stack trace of an interactive error in the Chrome JS console:

```
try { 
    throw new Error(); 
} catch (e) { 
    console.error(e.stack); 
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work if a non-`Error` object is thrown.

Comment: This works quite well. The data is formatted differently but all there (most important to me is line number). If a non `Error` object is thrown my stacktrace information will be lost to me, correct? Since we are retrieving it from the `Error` object in this case

Comment: Yes, same for any custom error object that isn't based on JS's standard Error objects. I tried setting a breakpoint in the `catch` clause when `throw`ing a string, trying to see if Chrome creates some sort of proper exception object internally one could use – no such luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Just a note: MobileSafari does not appear to provide a "stack" property to its errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your code.

You are missing a closing brace:

```
function otherStuff() { return ['a','b',undefined,'c']; //} where am i?
function doStuff() {
    var x = otherStuff();
    var z = parseInt(x[2]); // this will throw an error
}
```

---

Side point:

`parseInt(undefined)` does **not** throw an error. case in point: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Zequj/2/