# Throwing a stack trace without blocking execution

Tags: javascript, stack-trace

I've got a bug I'm trying to track down deep in some javascript code. It's the wonderful type of bug that doesn't really crash anything, and doesn't throw any errors, but significantly bogs down performance for the page.

I want to get the stack trace when a certain variable is undefined, but if I do something like this:

```
if(typeof a === 'undefined'){
    throw 'A is undefined';
}
```

my code will crash and stop executing, which is kind of a pain since I'm expecting quite a few things to throw this error, and I'd rather not have to restart the page ad fix each one before I get to the one that I need to fix.

Is there a way to throw an error and get a stack trace (or just get the stack trace) without blocking execution of the code?

I'm debugging in chrome, if that makes a difference.

Comment: See [Getting stack trace for an error when running code from the console in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7812682/218196)

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'd never used `console.error` before.